# docker container named dreamy_ritchie?

Tags: docker

I am learning how to use docker, I was a able to run multiple containers and everything is working fine, but there is one issue, when I stop all the containers, and then run: docker ps,
it doesn't show anything, but when I run: docker ps -a, it shows this:

```
bc39a16a9ac6   1c5b0a98ac9d  "/bin/sh -c 'chmod -…"  .... dreamy_ritchie
```

it is so strange, the container **dreamy_ritchie**, I didn't create that one, is it a virus? or is a docker internal container? thanks

Comment: Can you type `docker ps -a --no-trunc=true `?

Comment: docker ps will list all the running containers whereas docker ps -a will list all the containers. Since you haven’t specified any name to your container when it was created, a random name got assigned to it and in this case it was dreamy_ritchie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't supply a name to the container you create, docker will assign one of the form "adjective_scientist", where "adjective" is from a list of adjectives, and "scientist" is from a list of scientists and mathematicians.

It's a way of assigning a unique name to the container that is easier to work with than, say, 08fd482ac8913ed7.